# android: ArrayAdapter executing only one time in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter

I'm parsing a JSon file which has 5 football teams and each of them have played 4 games. 
I created a Wrapper class `OutputClass` to store all the details of each team i.e. number of games played, won, drawn and lost. 
Since there are 5 teams, I created a List of `OutputClass`.
So after passing the value to `onPostExecute`, I invoke an adapter called `FootballAdapter`.
This adapter is executed only one time.
Even if I change my position value to 2 or 3 in `outputClassList.get(int position)`, I get the same result in `Toast` as you can see in the image below.
I checked if the `outputClassList` is empty but its not. 
Objects is a list, that is passed from:

```
FootballAdapter adapter= new FootballAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row,result);
        jsonList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The above code is in `onPostExecute` method of `AsyncTask`.

```
public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,List<OutputClass>> {

    @Override
    protected List<OutputClass> doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection=null;
        BufferedReader r=null;

        try {
            URL url=new URL(params[0]);

            connection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            InputStream stream= connection.getInputStream();
            r= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((stream)));
            StringBuffer stringBuffer=new StringBuffer();
            String line="";
            while((line=r.readLine())!=null){
                stringBuffer.append(line);
            }

            String finalJSON=stringBuffer.toString();


            /// read and parse JSON file for desired output.....

            JSONObject parentObject= new JSONObject(finalJSON);

            // gets the name of all the objects namels alpha, bravo charlie etc etc
            JSONArray names=parentObject.names();

            // multiple objets for each team.....
            List<OutputClass> outputClassList =new ArrayList<>();

            String games[]=new String[4];
            int finalScore[]=new int[names.length()];
            int gd[]=new int[names.length()];
            int won[]=new int[names.length()];
            int draw[]=new int[names.length()];
            int lost[]=new int[names.length()];



            JSONObject[] mainObject=new JSONObject[names.length()];
            for(int i=0;i<names.length();i++){

                String teamName=names.getString(i);
                mainObject[i]=parentObject.getJSONObject(teamName);

                //outputClass[i].name=teamName;
                // Gets the game data for each game....

                games[0]=mainObject[i].getString("match_1");
                games[1]=mainObject[i].getString("match_2");
                games[2]=mainObject[i].getString("match_3");
                games[3]=mainObject[i].getString("match_4");

                // Calculates the final score and goal difference for each team.

                for(int j=0;j<4;j++) {
                    String score[] = games[j].split("-");
                    int score1 = Integer.parseInt(score[0]);
                    int score2 = Integer.parseInt(score[1]);

                    if (score1 > score2) {
                        finalScore[i] += 3;
                        won[i]++;
                    }
                    else if (score1 == score2) {
                        finalScore[i] += 1;
                        draw[i]++;
                    }else{
                        lost[i]++;
                    }
                    gd[i]+=score1-score2;

                }



                // Calculating the position based on final score and Goal Difference...

                OutputClass outputClass=new OutputClass();
                outputClass.goalDifference=gd[i];
                outputClass.draw=draw[i];
                outputClass.finalScore=finalScore[i];
                outputClass.lost=lost[i];
                outputClass.won=won[i];
                outputClass.played=4;
                outputClass.name=teamName;

                outputClassList.add(outputClass);


            }
            //Arrays.sort(outputClass,OutputClass.FinalScoreComparator);
            //Arrays.sort(outputClass,new OutputClass().FinalScoreComparator);
            Collections.sort(outputClassList,new OutputClass().FinalScoreComparator);

            Log.i(TAG,"Final Scre: "+outputClassList.get(0).finalScore+" won : "+outputClassList.get(0).won);
            Log.i(TAG,"Final Scre: "+outputClassList.get(1).finalScore+" won : "+outputClassList.get(1).won);
            Log.i(TAG,"Final Scre: "+outputClassList.get(2).finalScore+" won : "+outputClassList.get(2).won);
            Log.i(TAG,"Final Scre: "+outputClassList.get(3).finalScore+" won : "+outputClassList.get(3).won);
            //return stringBuffer.toString();
            return outputClassList;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
            try {
                if(r!=null)
                    r.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override

    protected void onPostExecute(List<OutputClass> result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        FootballAdapter adapter= new FootballAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row,result);
        jsonList.setAdapter(adapter);

        //to remove the button and text view after clicking them...
        imageButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        jsonData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //showing the list.....
        setContentView(jsonList);


    }


}

public class FootballAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<OutputClass>{

    private List<OutputClass> outputClassList;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public FootballAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<OutputClass> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        outputClassList = objects;
        this.resource=resource;
        inflater =(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView== null)
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,null);


        TextView rank;
        TextView played;
        TextView won;
        TextView lost;
        TextView draw;
        TextView gd;

        rank=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.rank);
        played=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.played);
        won=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.won);
        lost=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lost);
        draw=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.draw);
        gd=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.gd);

        if(rank!=null)
            played.setText("Played: " + outputClassList.get(position).played);
        if(won!=null)
            won.setText("Won: " + outputClassList.get(position).won);
        if(lost!=null)
            lost.setText("Lost: " + outputClassList.get(position).lost);
        if(draw!=null)
            draw.setText("Draw: " + outputClassList.get(position).draw);
        if(gd!=null)
            gd.setText("Goal Diff: " + outputClassList.get(position).goalDifference);


        Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Played: "+outputClassList.get(4).played+"Won: "+outputClassList.get(4).won,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

This is the log file that i created ot check if the outputClassList is empty or not :

```
I/enpFootball: Final Scre: 8 won : 2
I/enpFootball: Final Scre: 7 won : 2
I/enpFootball: Final Scre: 7 won : 2
I/enpFootball: Final Scre: 5 won : 1
```

A snipped of `ListView` can be seen at the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably in the line

```
rank=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.rank);
```

ArrayAdapter does not have findViewById() (see [ArrayAdapter Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html))

Since the above line is working, you probably have your FootballAdapter class defined as a nested class inside a context (e.g. Activity or Fragment) from which it is using the findViewById() method. In this case, you will be searching for the "first" widget with the specified id in the entire context. So, your adapter is infact executing for all the items in the list, but each time it is called, it overwrites the first widget (e.g. the first. R.id.rank, and the first R.id.played, etc.)

Try this instead

```
rank= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rank);
```

This way you are referring to the TextView inside the List Item that the adapter is supposed to fill and not the first item in the entire context. (See [View Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html))

Comment: Thanks a ton man @Ahmed, I found the exact same answer by trial and error but didn't know the Why. Now I know.

Answer (score 0):

try to print your result of postexecute() and see what you are getting there in your postupdate ,after that you would know that what exactly the problem is ,if you are not able to understand then again post some more information about your response and adapter class